# Bitcoin payment verification

Tags: verification, merkle-tree

I am having a tough time in understanding how Bitcoin payment verification works:

1. How is Merkle tree related to Bitcoin blocks?
2. Had Merkle tree not been there, what would have been the problem?

Comment: Sherlock, would you mind editing your question so that it only covers a single topic? (For example, editing your question so that it only contains 1 and 2.) It makes information [easier to search for](http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/426/should-we-split-up-posts-that-ask-many-questions-at-once). Remember, it's totally fine to have multiple questions on the front page at once.

Comment: Sure, I won't mind